# Analogical reasoning without language

Tags: language, reason, thinking

Can we performs analogical reasoning without language, and if so does that say anything about us?

I think so: comparing the feeling in our gut from eating bad food to life at sea. Is that analogical reasoning? Can it be pre-verbal? Is it habitual/unavoidable? Does it link to intuition?